# Point domain name to specific folder on server

Tags: apache, nginx, dns, virtualhost, cname

I am currently working on a CMS type of site where users can create websites on my server.

I want to be able to create subdomains for the user's website for them to see the preview.

The next step would be for users to be able to point their domain name to my server, and when users go to the domain it would go to their own designated folder on my server.

How would I go about doing this automatically with php, I have been looking for solutions with no avail.

I currently have a Virtual Server with hostgator. Please advise, or point me in the right direction. Any solutions are welcome as well, I am pretty much stuck at this point.

Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

For example, if my domain is www.mydomain.com, when a user makes an account, the subdomain username.mydomain.com is created. Later down the line, if the user buys the domain name www.userdomain.com, I want to make it so that if www.userdomain.com is entered, it shows what is on www.mydomain.com/userdomain. The URL should still show www.userdomain.com

Comment: I think you can do this using DNS-recods like a `CNAME record`.

Comment: I do not think that would work, I gave an example above to make what I am trying to do more clear. CNAME would only work for the same host domain I think.

Comment: Now I understand. Have you ever heard of cloacking?

Comment: As in cloaking the URL?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is depends on which web server you are using ?(apache / nginx or any other)

1. You need to have separate directory for each sub domain you created
2. In your virtual host configuration you need to match the host name and get the subdomain as a parameter to set the root directory for your host name.
3. CNAME is also possible but if you can tell your web server there is a possibility for detailed answer.

Comment: The VPS is running Apache on a CentOS Linux System. If the client changes their DNS to point to my nameservers, what do I need to do on my end to make it so the domain points to their specific directory. I understand how to do the subdomain creation, a little stuck on the second part now. Also can it be done programmatically via PHP as to automate it.